# How to fix the compile error when include the opencv intrin_avx.hpp

Tags: opencv

can you give me some advice for the problem.

###### System information (version)

- OpenCV => 4.2.0
- Operating System / Platform => ubuntu 16.04 64 Bit
- Compiler => g++ 7.5.0

###### Detailed description

Compiling the single intrin_avx.hpp fails when using avx/avx2 supported device.

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o
In file included from /home/workspace/Test/test.cpp:2:0:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/hal/intrin_avx.hpp:17:1: error: ‘CV_CPU_OPTIMIZATION_HAL_NAMESPACE_BEGIN’ does not name a type
 CV_CPU_OPTIMIZATION_HAL_NAMESPACE_BEGIN
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/hal/intrin_avx.hpp:24:8: error: ‘__m256’ does not name a type
 inline __m256 _v256_combine(const __m128& lo, const __m128& hi)
        ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/hal/intrin_avx.hpp:27:8: error: ‘__m256d’ does not name a type
 inline __m256d _v256_combine(const __m128d& lo, const __m128d& hi)
        ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/hal/intrin_avx.hpp:30:35: error: ‘__m256i’ does not name a type
 inline int _v_cvtsi256_si32(const __m256i& a)
                                   ^~~~~~
...
```

###### Steps to reproduce

- test.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/core/hal/intrin_avx.hpp"

int main() {
    printf("test\n");
    return 0; 
}
```

- CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.15)
PROJECT(test)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# avx
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mavx2")

# opencv
MESSAGE(STATUS "FIND OpenCV on LINUX.")
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(test test.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
        test
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

Comment: Maybe that file should be included by other headers like some Windows files. Can you try including `hal.hpp` first?

Comment: You are right. This file could not be directly included. I fix it by  including opencv2/core/simd_intrinsics.hpp and adding -mavx2 compile flag.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/intrin-avx-hpp-compile-error/6677